# Angularjs filter doesn't work properly with Turkish characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

The filtering in Angular.js does not work correctly when using Turkish characters.

Input:

```
<div>
    Aranacak İfade: <input type="text" ng-model="searchKey" placeholder="Aramak için birşeyler girin">
</div>


<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="personel in personeller | filter:searchKey">
<td> {{ personel.isim }} </td>
<td> {{ personel.soyisim }} </td>
<td> {{ personel.cinsiyet }} </td>
<td> {{ personel.maas }} </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

searchKey is "istanbul" and my table has "İstanbul" value. But no results in this case. Why is this problem caused?

Also, I tried as follows but doesn't work:

```
ng-repeat="personel in personeller | filter:searchKey || searchKey.toLocaleUpperCase('tr')
```

Answer (score 2):

By a direct `===` comparison, `İstanbul` doesn't equal `istanbul`, and a simple direct comparison is all the an AngularJS filter does by default.

Even if you do `toLocaleUpperCase()` on each string, they won't be equal, since uppercase `i` isn't `İ`, but `I`. Nor will `toLocaleUpperCase()` help, since lowercase `İ` isn't `i`, but `i̇`.

What you need is `localeCompare()`, with the right options:

`str1.localeCompare(str2, 'tr', {sensitivity: 'base'})`

The value of the above will be `0` when the two strings match, disregarding case and diacritical marks. Drop this into your web console:

`'İstanbul'.localeCompare('istanbul', 'tr', {sensitivity: 'base'})`

...and you'll see how it comes out as `0`.

It's been a long time since I've worked in AngularJS rather than the newer Angular, so I can't offer you the exact code you need offhand, but the AngularJS docs show this:

`{{ filter_expression | filter : expression : comparator : anyPropertyKey}}`

...and all you should have to do is pass a `comparator` argument that uses the above `localeCompare()`.

*Oh, and of course...*

[`'İstanbul' !== 'Constantinople'`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xo0X77OBJUg)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I use the search filter. For this reason, words don't have to be equal. it will suffice to include one of the data in the list. For example, if i write "ist", İstanbul should come from the list. How can I do that ?

Comment: Ah, that's trickier if you want to be able to do partial matches. Hidden behind the scenes of the way `localeCompare` works is the ability to strip away diacritical marks and case distinctions, but it's not exposed in such a way that you can take a string and simply lowercase or uppercase it with diacritical marks removed. I've written code to handle this sort of thing, but it's quite a long complicated mess -- a bit much to try to post here.

Comment: The basic idea is that you need to have a list of things to match with which have already been lowercased (or uppercased, whatever your preference) with diacritical marks removed, perform the same process on the input typed for searching, and then test if `searchStr === targetStr.substr(0, searchStr.length)`.

Comment: I have code on GitHub for this: https://github.com/kshetline/ks-util/blob/master/src/string-util.ts. The methods `stripLatinDiacriticals_lc` or `stripLatinDiacriticals_UC` would help here.